# Node.js Express block

Tags: node.js, express, blocking

My Problem is, that I'm planning to use express to cache all requests which I receiver for a certain amount of time until I send all responses at once. 
But unfortunately I can't receive a second request until I've responded to the first one. So I guess node / express is somehow blocking the further processing of other requests.

I build a minimal working example for you, so you can see better what I'm talking about.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var ca = [];

app.get('/hello.txt', function(req, res){
  ca.push(res);
  console.log("Push");
});

setInterval(function(){
  while (ca.length) {
    var res = ca.shift();
    res.send('Hello World');
    console.log("Send");
  }
},9000);

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

When I'm sending just one request to `localhost:3000` and wait for 9sec I'm able to send a second one. But when I send both without waiting for the callback of the interval, the second one is blocked until the first interval triggered.

Long Story short: Why is this blocking happening and what ways are there to avoid this blocking.

PS: It seems that the default http package shows another behavior http://blog.nemikor.com/2010/05/21/long-polling-in-nodejs/

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I see now. He is trying to empty the whole array after 9 seconds. I feel like this might be more of a client issue. I dont see anything here that should prevent multiple requests.

Comment: The requests aren't being blocked by each other. They're just being managed in a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) queue with `.push()` and `.shift()`. But, they can be sent in a different order, perhaps using `.pop()` for [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_(computing)) or accessing one directly with an index, `ca[2].send('Hello world');`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski he says they are blocked though.... Obatzer Can you go into more detail on how exactly you are sending these requests?

Comment: I agree with @InternalFX, request handling isn't being blocked here.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your support. I try to be more precisely now, but I guess I'll be for the best if you try to run this locally at your pc.  I send the request simply by calling the URL `localhost:3000/hello.txt` on chrome. So when I'm opening two tabs and click on 'send' at the same time, the console will print `Push` (9 sec later) `Send` `Push` (9 sec later) `send` ... so I'm estimating this means the second request is blocked until express responded to the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it with firefox and chrome to prevent serializing the requests...

Comment: @XuYin it may not seem like an answer, but it fixes the problem. His problem was unrelated to his question, so the solution is as well.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've got the solution.

The issue wasn't in my code, it was caused by Chrome. It seems that Chrome is serializing all requests, which target the same URL. But nevertheless it sends both request and won't serve the second request with the response of the first.

Anyway, thanks for you help!